# Comparing 2 tables and trace the changed columns and other set to null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have situation when comparind 2 tables. One is current data and other is a snapshot of previous the data. The result of the comparison is stored into a #temp table ( the row which was changed). After that I am comparing #temp table to the last snapshot data to trace changed columns.  I need For this I did a select statement :

I am thinking to add and ROW_NUMBER() windows function and may this will solve this.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide sample data so it is clear what data you are starting with.

Comment: I have putted some clear data

Comment: . . Your data is not clear.  You still have not shown what is in the two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be NULL comparisons within aggregation.  SQL Server's built-in aggregate functions ignore NULLs.  To test for any NULL values the query checks sum(case when [ADDRESS1] is null then 1 else 0 end)=0, etc.  Something like this

```
with nullif_cte as (
    select l.[ADDRESSID],
           nullif(l.[ADDRESS1], n.[ADDRESS1]) ADDRESS1,
           nullif(l.[ADDRESS2], n.[ADDRESS2]) ADDRESS2,
           nullif(l.[ADDRESS3], n.[ADDRESS3]) ADDRESS3,
           nullif(l.[ADDRESS4], n.[ADDRESS4]) ADDRESS4,
           nullif(l.[CITY], n.[CITY]) [CITY],
           nullif(l.[CLIENTID], n.[CLIENTID]) [CLIENTID],
           nullif(l.[COUNTRY_CODE], n.[COUNTRY_CODE]) [COUNTRY_CODE],
           nullif(l.[POST_CODE], n.[POST_CODE]) [POST_CODE]
    from #tempUpdatedAddress l 
         left join UpdatedEntityStg n ON n.[ADDRESSID] = n.[ADDRESSID])
select [ADDRESSID],
       case when sum(case when [ADDRESS1] is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 
                          then max([ADDRESS1]) else null end [ADDRESS1],
       case when sum(case when [ADDRESS2] is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 
                          then max([ADDRESS2]) else null end [ADDRESS2],
       case when sum(case when [ADDRESS3] is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 
                          then max([ADDRESS3]) else null end [ADDRESS3],
       case when sum(case when [ADDRESS4] is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 
                          then max([ADDRESS4]) else null end [ADDRESS4],
       case when sum(case when [CITY] is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 
                          then max([CITY]) else null end [CITY],
       case when sum(case when [CLIENTID] is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 
                          then max([CLIENTID]) else null end [CLIENTID],
       case when sum(case when [COUNTRY_CODE] is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 
                          then max([COUNTRY_CODE]) else null end [COUNTRY_CODE],
       case when sum(case when [POST_CODE] is null then 1 else 0 end)=0 
                          then max([POST_CODE]) else null end [POST_CODE]
from nullif_cte nc
group by [ADDRESSID];
```

Comment: HI Steve, thanks for the answer . I have an erorr : Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: Ok, I updated to fix that issue.  Please review.  Sample data would help btw

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `row_number()` or `outer apply`.  The latter changes the `FROM` clause to:

```
FROM #tempUpdatedAddress l OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) n.*
      FROM UpdatedEntityStg n 
      WHERE n.[ADDRESSID] = n.[ADDRESSID] 
      ORDER BY n.snapshotdate DESC
     ) n
```

Note:  You don't specify how you know the ordering of the snapshots, so I invented `snapshotdate` for the `ORDER BY`.  Use whatever column contains the ordering information.

Comment: Hi Gordon , The snapshotdate column has the same value for all those 5 rows

Comment: Seams that it is working well , thank you . BUT is I would have 2 addressid's in UpdatedEntityStg table. I will work the same?

Comment: @Serii . . . This preserves all rows in `#tempUpdatedAddress` with at most one row from `UpdatedEntityStg`.

Comment: I have tested and on others Addressid's it is viewed incorrectly.  Coould you please apply a method with RowNumber(). Thnak you